# get visible index of physical - reverse function of hook modifyRow of Handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

got a simple question, how can i get visible indexes(row,col) of cell if i have initial(physical) indexes of **Handsontable**!?

In other words, reverse function of `hot.runHooks('modifyRow',row)` and `hot.runHooks('modifyCol',col)` ?!

thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the answer for my question by myself ))
these are: `hot.runHooks('unmodifyRow',row)` and `hot.runHooks('unmodifyCol',col)`

but it doesnt counted if there are filters applied... thou